# Hosting Multiple react app in cpanel on singe domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cpanel

I had delveloped an react application which I want to upload it to cpanel. I had my website also running on the same domain. 
Example:
https://www.mywebsite.com host my web content for selling roses.

Now I want to upload my application(APP1) developed in node js as backend and reactjs as front end.
But in future I need to upload similiar other websites too. So I want to create a folder on root and inside or the root i want to upload my application (APP1). 
In future if I develop another application(APP2) I want to upload it to same domain in another folder on root (APP2).

My folder structure will be as
Root
   ...WEBSITE FILES
   ...APP1
     ......app1_files
   ...APP2
     ......app2 files

Now how to deploy my APP1 and APP2 on my domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the 'package.json' file in your React Application, add a package name ("homepage": "YOUR WEBSITE LANDING PAGE LINK")
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YTPo.png)
2. Go to the terminal of your editor and type "npm run build".
3. Navigate to the Application folder, you will find a folder named "build", upload all the files to the website directory.

   **HOW TO MAKE A DIRECTORY?**
4. Go to your cpanel > public_html (this will be your root folder): you can upload your files here.
5. If you want to make a directory or another application within the same domain just make a new folder inside public_html and upload the application within that folder and the application will be available by typing: YOURWEBSITE.COM/FOLDERNAME